# Colorbox images show up small once after opened for video on same page, using jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, video, colorbox

I have a webpage where a couple of links are provided to view image gallery and (YouTube/Vimeo) video.

If the image gallery link is clicked and viewed before viewing the video popup, then it is all good and showing nice. But once after the video link clicked and viewed, and go back to open the image gallery again, then the colorbox for image view is opening in a short window.

Seems some window/size parameters need to be reset for image gallery?

Have any of you come across such issue?

```
<link href="css/gallery_colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
<script src="jquery-colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

<script>
//$.noConflict();
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    if(jQuery(window).width() < 800)
    {
        jQuery(".photo_gallery").colorbox({rel:'photo_gallery', maxWidth:"100%", maxHeight:"600px", current:"{current}/{total}"});
    } else { 
        jQuery(".photo_gallery").colorbox({rel:'photo_gallery', maxWidth:"800px", maxHeight:"600px", current:"{current}/{total}"});   
    }

    jQuery(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, fastIframe:false, width:"450px", height:"480px", transition:"fade", scrolling:false});
    jQuery(".youtube_video").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:740, innerHeight:490, 
                                          onComplete : function() {   
                             jQuery('.cboxIframe').parent("#cboxLoadedContent").addClass('iframewrap');
                             jQuery('.cboxIframe').closest("#colorbox").addClass('coloriframebox');
                                           }  
                                      });

   });

</script>
```

The page is written in php and invokes the colorbox view by `<div id="abc" class="youtube_video">` or `<div id="xyz" class="photo_gallery">` or so.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you need to remove the classes that you added when viewing the video.  Colorbox reuses it's DOM elements between uses, so changes you make, such as adding classes, inline styles, adding/removing elements, etc. will persist.  Use the onClosed callback to cleanup the changes you don't want to persist.

Try replacing this:

```
jQuery(".youtube_video").colorbox({
    iframe:true, 
    innerWidth:740, 
    innerHeight:490, 
    onComplete: function() {   
        jQuery('.cboxIframe').parent("#cboxLoadedContent").addClass('iframewrap');
        jQuery('.cboxIframe').closest("#colorbox").addClass('coloriframebox');
    }  
});
```

With this:

```
jQuery(".youtube_video").colorbox({
    iframe:true, 
    innerWidth:740, 
    innerHeight:490, 
    onComplete: function() {   
        jQuery("#cboxLoadedContent").addClass('iframewrap');
        jQuery("#colorbox").addClass('coloriframebox');
    },
    onClosed: function() {
        jQuery("#cboxLoadedContent").removeClass('iframewrap');
        jQuery("#colorbox").removeClass('coloriframebox');
    },
});
```

Comment: Tried it out. Still the same. After closing the video pop-up (not necessarily to complete the video play though)I by clicking the X button and come back to the image gallery, same issue persists.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think any more help can be given based on the available information.  You'll need to provide a demonstration of the problem.

Comment: Perfect, it worked like a charm. That was the issue, adding but not removing after completion. The fix worked perfect. Thanks so much, Jack. You rock :)